# Deleting a course from array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am having issues with determining what the given algorithm is asking for.I'm not sure how to delete a location within an array or assign a null to the last spot in an array. Here is the algorithm:

```
found = searchToDelete( course )

IF (found == -1) THEN

Display message that course is not in student’s schedule
ELSE

IF (found == ( position of last course in array) THEN

course number = course number -1
         ELSE

FOR (index = found, index < course number, index++)

schedule [index] = schedule [index + 1]
                  END FOR

course number = course number - 1
          END IF
END IF
```

Here is my code:

```
public void dropCourse(String courseName){

found = searchToDelete(course);
int index = 0;
  if (found == -1){
  System.out.println("Course not in schedule");

   if (found = index(6)){
   courseNumber = courseNumber -1;

  for ( index = found, index < courseNumber, index ++);
  {
  schedule[index] = schedule[index + 1];
  }courseNumber = courseNumber -1;
   }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Why don't you format your question a little better? It will be easier to read.

Comment: Yeah. Can you show  `searchToDelete()`

Comment: would it be more helpful to display my entire code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have to implement the algorithm exactly like the pseudo-code, I would suggest you use a List class like the [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).
The ArrayList class has a lot of useful functions that would make your code easier.

If you have to use an array I suggest you take a look at the [arraycopy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) method to replace your original array, as you cannot resize an array in Java.

You can, of course, set the entry `schedule[courseNumber]` to null (after decrementing the courseNumber), but then you will possibly wind up with arrays that mostly consist of null, and, since you cannot resize the array, you would probably run into problems when adding something to it in case it is full.

Comment: unfortunately I cannot use arraylist for this assignment so how would I set up the null for schedule[courseNumber], would it look like schedule[courseNumber] = null and place that after courseNumber -1 @sandbo00